# Extracting non repeating data

Tags: google-sheets

[image: Example]

Hi,
is there a way to ignore the duplicated values in columns A and B (highlighted) and extract ones that don't repeat (column C extracted manually for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Formula

```
=SORT( MAP(UNIQUE({A1:A4;B1:B4}),
       LAMBDA(x, IF(COUNTIF(A1:B4,x)=1,x,))) )
```

[image]

##### CODE NOTES

```
1 |  =SORT(
2 |       MAP(UNIQUE({A1:A4;B1:B4}),
3 |           LAMBDA(x, 
4 |                 IF(COUNTIF(A1:B4,x)=1,x,))))
```

| Line | Notes |
| --- | --- |
| #1 | Wrap formula in SORT |
| #2 | **A.** Create 1 column array from data in 2 columns `{A1:A4;B1:B4}` **B.** Get list of unique values from new array `UNIQUE({A1:A4;B1:B4})` **C.** Map list of unique values into LAMBDA function `MAP(UNIQUE({A1:A4;B1:B4})` |
| #3 | Define a variable name `x` for values mapped into LAMBDA `LAMBDA(x` |
| #4 | **A.** Count the occurrences in the source data `A1:B4` of each mapped value `COUNTIF(A1:B4,x)` **B.** If occurrences (count) equals 1, then the mapped value is unique and returned `IF(COUNTIF(A1:B4,x)=1,x,)` |

Answer (score 1):

For a simple case like this you could use the **exactly_once** argument of UNIQUE by combining the two columns to be processed into a single column using a literal:

```
=unique({A1:A;B1:B},,1)
```

- [UNIQUE Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10522653?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Another option, in case you may have repeated values inside the same column, here's another process that doesn't involve counting:

In this case, I filter both A and B columns by checking if the value can be found in the other column. When MATCH doesn't found the value, returns #N/A, and ISNA grabs it and returns TRUE; meaning it will be selected for your list.

```
={FILTER(A2:A,INDEX(ISNA(MATCH(A2:A,B2:B,0))),A2:A<>"");
FILTER(B2:B,INDEX(ISNA(MATCH(B2:B,A2:A,0))),B2:B<>"")}
```

[image]